# .NET Maui IOS Release build doesn't contain iTunesArtwork?

Tags: icons, app-store, maui

Just wondering about the white picture after deploying my app to itunesconnect.

[image: itunesconnect screenshot]

After renaming the .ipa file to .zip and browsing through it it noticed that .net has not include an itunesartwork... file. Only the appicon and my icons for the tabbar included.

I created the .ipa with the terminal command:

`dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true`

Did i miss something? Is there an optional parameter to force Visual Studio 2022 to create that 1024x1024 graphic?

If i look in the iossimulator folder for that app it includes all the graphics, and i think the file `appiconItunesArtwork.png` is the important one?

[image: ios simulator folder for app]

Comment: Does appicon work well when deploying on physical device? You could try setting the appicon BaseSize value which should be divisible by 8 in project file.

Comment: Here is my Icon Entry:  `<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" BaseSize="128,128" Color="#000000"/>`

Comment: The problem is the the .net compiler does not generator the ITunesArtwork File!

Comment: have you tried the workaround on Github? [App Icon for iOS is not created when app icon is not a multiplier](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9067)

Comment: Yes, my icon size is a multiplier from 8, but Visual Studio does nothing with it. Do you know if there is a way to include the icons in all resolutions in the ipa and disable the auto sizing of the graphics from Visual Studio?

Comment: Opened an issue in the .NET Maui Repository on github for this case: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12085

Comment: Have you found any solution or workaround to this issue?

Comment: Maybe my Release Settings are missing something? Could you post your working Release Settings from your project file, please?

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <CodesignEntitlement>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlement> 
  <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution:Systems &amp; Co. (F5LGNYXS4N)</CodesignKey>
  <CodesignProvision>AppstoreSigning</CodesignProvision>
  <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
 </PropertyGroup>